# Swiftui updating menu component lists dynamically

Tags: menu, swiftui

I have two menu components and need to update the number of elements in the second menu once a selection is made in the fist menu component. Here is a simplified sample code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var menu1List: [Int]
    @State var menu2List: [String]
    @State var currentIndex: Int
    
    init() {
        _menu1List = State(initialValue: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 , 7, 8])
        _menu2List = State(initialValue: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"])
        _currentIndex = State(initialValue: 0)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            MenuView(menu1List: $menu1List, menu2List: $menu2List, currentIndex: $currentIndex)
            ForEach(menu2List.indices) { index in
                Text("Item \(menu2List[index])") \\Menu 1 selection in MenuView causes index out of range exception.
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct MenuView : View {
    
    @Binding var menu1List: [Int]
    @Binding var menu2List: [String]
    @Binding var currentIndex: Int

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Menu {
                ForEach(menu1List.indices) { index in
                    Button(action: {
                        menu2List = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
                    }
                    ) {
                        Text("\(menu1List[index])")
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Menu1")
                Image(systemName: "chevron.down.circle")
            }
            
            Spacer()

            Menu {
                ForEach(menu2List.indices) { index in
                    Button(action: {
                        currentIndex = index
                    }
                    ) {
                        Text("\(menu2List[index])")
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Menu2")
                Image(systemName: "chevron.down.circle")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

When I lower the number of elements in Menu 2 I get an Index out of range exception as indicated in the code. Is there any way to fix this? I would greatly appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You used static variant of `ForEach` constructor (ie it expected that data is not changed), but if you want to change content of `ForEach` you must use dynamic one (with `id:`)

```
    ForEach(menu2List.indices, id: \.self) { index in    // << here !!
        Text("Item \(menu2List[index])")
    }
```

Comment: Worked brilliantly! Also thanks for the explanation for the difference between static and dynamic ForEach.